# duktape how to parse argument of type String Object (similarly Number object) in duktape c function

Tags: duktape

How to type check the String object/Number object argument types in duktape c function and parse the value from String object/Number object. There is generic api like duk_is_object() but I need the correct object type to parse the value .

```
ex: 
ecmascript code
  var str1 = new String("duktape");
   var version = new Number(2.2);
 dukFunPrintArgs(str1,str2); 

duktape c function :
dukFunPrintArgs(ctx)
{
  // code to know whether the args is of type String Object / Number Object

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find the information how to register a C function in duktape? That place certainly also has details on how to access the parameters passed to it. Already on the homepage of duktape.org you can find a Getting Started example:

```
3 Add C function bindings

To call a C function from Ecmascript code, first declare your C functions:

/* Being an embeddable engine, Duktape doesn't provide I/O
 * bindings by default.  Here's a simple one argument print()
 * function.
 */
static duk_ret_t native_print(duk_context *ctx) {
  printf("%s\n", duk_to_string(ctx, 0));
  return 0;  /* no return value (= undefined) */
}

/* Adder: add argument values. */
static duk_ret_t native_adder(duk_context *ctx) {
  int i;
  int n = duk_get_top(ctx);  /* #args */
  double res = 0.0;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    res += duk_to_number(ctx, i);
  }

  duk_push_number(ctx, res);
  return 1;  /* one return value */
}

Register your functions e.g. into the global object:

duk_push_c_function(ctx, native_print, 1 /*nargs*/);
duk_put_global_string(ctx, "print");
duk_push_c_function(ctx, native_adder, DUK_VARARGS);
duk_put_global_string(ctx, "adder");

You can then call your function from Ecmascript code:

duk_eval_string_noresult(ctx, "print('2+3=' + adder(2, 3));");
```

One of the core concepts in duktape are stacks. The value stack is where parameters are stored. Read more on the [Getting Started](http://duktape.org/guide.html#programming.4) page.